# Hidden fields have the wrong value after first POST

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view on which the user can log time spent on an Activity using an HTML form. So that view loops through a list of all Activities and generates a log time form (contained in the _LogTime partial view) for each one. The only piece of information passed to the partial view from the Index view is the ActivityId, which is placed in a hidden form. The rest of the required information is provided via the from by the user.

The problem I'm having is that once I submit one of the forms, the hidden field for all of the forms is set to the ActivityId of the form I just submitted. It's worth noting that when the page first loads (before I submit any forms), the hidden fields are correct, and when I submit a form for the first time, the correct Activity gets time logged to it (and none of the others erroneously get time logged). But any form submissions after that will only log time to the Activity I first submitted the form for.

Any idea what's going on here? Why are all of the hidden fields being set to the same ActivityId? And why only after the first POST? Let me know if you need any clarification of the problem.

Models:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserActivity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Views:

```
// Index View
@foreach (Activity activity in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_LogTime", new UserActivity(activity.ActivityId))
}

// _LogTime Partial View
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActivityId)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Duration)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)

        <input type="submit" value="LOG TIME" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ActivityController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext _db = new DbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.Activities.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserActivity activity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.UserActivities.Add(activity);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(_db.Activities.ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is due to the fact that the html helper methods automatically update form elements with post variables of the same name. The values are stored in ModelState. One way to fix this is to remove the offending entry from ModelState.

Another possible fix is to do a redirect instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserActivity activity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.UserActivities.Add(activity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Remove the ActivityId from your ModelState before returning the View.
    ModelState.Remove("ActivityId")

    return View(_db.Activities.ToList());
}
```

As witnessed by the comments below, use of the Remove method can indicate a deeper issue with the flow of your application. I do agree with Erik on that point. As he points out, redesigning the flow of an application can be a time consuming task.

When encountering the behavior indicated by the question, if there is a way to solve the problem without modifying ModelState, that would be a preferred solution. A case in point might be where more than a single element were affected by this issue.

For completeness, here is an alternate solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserActivity activity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.UserActivities.Add(activity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Towards the end of silencing my critic, here is the rewrite that he could not come up with.

```
// Index View
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ActivityId)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Duration)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Date)
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="LOG TIME ENTRIES" />

}

// Controller Post Method
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<UserActivity> activities)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach( var activity in activities ) 
        {
            var first = _db.UserActivities
                  .FirstOrDefault(row => row.ActivityId == activity.ActivityId );
            if ( first == null ) {
               _db.UserActivities.Add(activity);
            } else {
               first.Duration = activity.Duration;
               first.Date = activity.Date;
            }
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    // when the ModelState is invalid, we want to 
    // retain posted values and display errors.
    return View(_db.Activities.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation when posting code blocks like this.

Comment: Not really, it's just code, explain what change you made and why.

Comment: @erik I disagree. Instead of down voting, offer a better answer, assuming you have one. I also mentioned an alternative in the requested edit.

Comment: @B2K - You can disagree all you like, it doesn't change the fact that his code is going to generate invalid html (multiple items with the same ID's).  You're only treating the symptom.  Fixing this requires completely rewriting his code, which i'm not going to do.  You should NEVER have to remove items from the ModelState.  If you are, then it's a symptom of a different problem and you're just masking it.  Fix the real problem.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Please tell me why Microsoft added a Remove method to ModelState, if it was never intended to be used. They also offer a ModelState.Clear command. Neither of these are deprecated. They can be used when the application's needs require it.

Comment: @B2K - Because it's a dictionary, and the framework needs to be able to clear it and add or remove items..  That doesn't mean you should be doing it in user code.  There are lots of things you CAN do, like put your database access in your razor code.  That doesn't mean you SHOULD do it.  The point here is that manually manipulating the ViewState is a code smell, and in this case is indicative of a larger problem.  Your solution just hides that larger problem.

Comment: @B2K - Also, While your alternate solution still just hides the problem by treating the symptom, at least it's slightly better because it's using the preferred PRG pattern.  It doesn't, however address the problem that if the `ModelState.IsValid` is false, *EVERY* ActivityId in eacy row will have the same ActivityId set, because they all use the same ID's and Names.  This is my point about there being a larger problem.  You can pub band-aids in to address individual symptoms, but fixing the real problem is the solution, and the real problem is generating fields with the same ID's and names

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You are incorrect. He uses a separate form for each UserActivity. Only one of them is submitted. If you're going to take the time to blast someone trying to provide an answer, why not offer something constructive. All you've done is criticize everything I've written. As I stated in my original reply to you, offer him the correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54401/discussion-between-b2k-and-erik-funkenbusch).

Answer (score 0):

I never use global variables in my Controller.
I rather put all my hidden values, also those in the foreach partial view, in the form.

That way, you pass the entire list and add one after that.
Now I think that you pass an empty row and add the last one to that.

To be sure, you can put a breakpoint in the post function.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // Index View
    @foreach (Activity activity in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_LogTime", new UserActivity(activity.ActivityId))
    }

    // _LogTime Partial View

    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActivityId)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Duration)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)

        <input type="submit" value="LOG TIME" />
    </fieldset>
}
```